# How checked checkbox can change div's z-index?

Tags: css, checkbox

I have a span with paypal button. I must make this paypal button avialable for pressing only after user confirms TOS. For this i think to lay over the span with the paypal button another div with unchecked checkbox, opacity and z-index. The user checks the checkbox and the layed over div gets such a z-index, so the span with paypal button will be over it and can be pressed.

I need something like

**HTML**

```
<div class="with_zindex">
    <input type="checkbox​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​">
<span class="here_is_paypal_button"></span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.with_zindex{
background-color:#fafafa;
    opacity: .5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity: .5;
z-index:1000;
}
.with_zindex + input[type=checkbox]:checked {
z-index:-1000;
}
```

But this don't work for me (there are only given first formattings, which are not chenged by checking / unchecking checkbox).

Comment: Why don't you try to enable/disable the paypal button based on the status of the checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Suggestion

Instead, you can initially have the PayPal button disabled and you can enable it once the user clicks on the checkbox.

#### HTML (jQuery Version)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="terms" 
       onclick="$('#paypal').removeAttr('disabled');" />
<input type="image" name="paypal" id="paypal" disabled="disabled" />
```

#### HTML (JavaScript Version)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="terms" 
       onclick="document.getElementById('paypal').removeAttribute('disabled');" />
<input type="image" name="paypal" id="paypal" disabled="disabled" />
```

---

#### Else if you insist on `z-index`:

You need to give `position: relative;` for `z-index` to work. And there is no negative `z-index`!

```
.with_zindex {
    background-color:#fafafa;
    opacity: .5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity: .5;
    position: relative;
    z-index:1000;
}
.with_zindex + input[type=checkbox]:checked {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

---

#### Your required answer

#### HTML

```
<div class="with_zindex">
    <input type="Checkbox" name="TOS" value="read">
    <span class="catItemExtraFieldsValue">
        <img src="http://gutgeordnet.de/reise/images/epaypal_de.gif">
    </span>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.with_zindex {position: relative;}

.with_zindex input[type=checkbox] {
    background-color:#fafafa;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 50;
    top: 10px;
    left: -35px;
    width: 135px;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: top;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.with_zindex input[type=checkbox] + .catItemExtraFieldsValue {
    position: relative;
    opacity: .5;
    -moz-opacity: .5;
    z-index: 45;
}

.with_zindex input[type=checkbox]:after {
    content: 'I accept';
    font-size: 14px;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: tahoma;
}

.with_zindex input[type=checkbox]:checked {position: static; display: none;}

.with_zindex input[type=checkbox]:checked + .catItemExtraFieldsValue {
    position: static;
    background-color: transparent;
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-opacity: 1;
}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/35cQz/

Comment: Why this z-index solution doesn't work for me? The css of .with_zindex was applied, but the paypal-button is clickable, even if checkbox is unchecked too. And, after i check the checkbox and look into the code with firebug, the checkbox doesn't got label "checked".

Comment: Dude, did you read what I answered? **You need to give `position: relative;` for `z-index` to work. And there is no negative `z-index`!**

Comment: sure, i have read and used it exactly so, like you say: with position:relative; for the div and no negative z-index.

Comment: Got your issue. The `+` operator is used only to select siblings. Not children. See the updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/35cQz/

Answer (score 0):

I got it on this way:

**HTML:**

```
<input class="Checkbox1" name="TOS" id="TOS" value="read" type="checkbox";"/>
```

**JS**

```
var $K2 = jQuery.noConflict();

 $K2(document).ready(function(){

//$K2('#TOS').attr('checked', false);
//$K2('input[type=image]').attr("class", "agbunchecked");
//$K2('input[type=image]').bind("click", giveAllert);

if(!$K2('#TOS').attr('checked')) //Existenzcheck
{
    $K2('input[type=image]').attr("class", "agbunchecked");
    $K2('input[type=image]').bind("click", giveAllert);
}

function giveAllert()
{
    alert("\Pleas check the checkbox!");
    return false;
}

$K2('#TOS').change(function(event){
    if(this.checked) 
    {
        $K2('input[type=image]').attr("class", "agbchecked");
        $K2('input[type=image]').unbind("click");
    }
    else
    {
        $K2('input[type=image]').attr("class", "agbunchecked");
        $K2('input[type=image]').bind("click", giveAllert)
    }
});

  });
```

**CSS**

```
.agbunchecked{
background-color:#fafafa;
opacity: .5;
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
-moz-opacity: .5;
}
```